# PatternExpressions are not allowed to introduce new variables

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two types of relationship that can exist between two same nodes. I want to extract the nodes that only have `type1` and not `type2` relationship. My query is:

```sql
Match (n) where (n)-[:type1]-(m) and (not (n)-[:type2]-(m)) return n
```

This gives error:

```
PatternExpressions are not allowed to introduce new variables: 'm'. (line 1, column 32 (offset: 31))
"Match (n) where (n)-[:type1]-(m) and (not (n)-[:type2]-(m)) return n"
                               ^
```

Neither [Googling around](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjmnv_-ubHzAhU0zIsBHUDzB8IQFnoECBMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fneo4j-contrib.github.io%2Fcypher-dsl%2F2021.1.1%2Fproject-info%2Fapidocs%2Forg%2Fneo4j%2Fcypherdsl%2Fcore%2FRelationshipChain.html&usg=AOvVaw1ayYRCTXzjKZdhoLWAK9Lx) nor the documentation [Patterns - Neo4j Cypher Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/) give me any useful help. Do you know why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this.

```
match(n)-[:type1]-(m)
where not (n)-[:type2]-(m)
return n
```

Comment: I see. But do you know why the error happens? Why should new variables not be allowed to introduce?

Comment: Neo4j document says "Note that you cannot introduce new variables here. Although it might look very similar to the MATCH patterns, the WHERE clause is all about eliminating matched paths. MATCH (a)-[*]->(b) is very different from WHERE (a)-[*]->(b). The first will produce a path for every path it can find between a and b, whereas the latter will eliminate any matched paths where a and b do not have a directed relationship chain between them."